# Hiding tab if no text / content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

Im trying to hide tabs which have no content using jQuery. I thought this would be relatively easy but can't seem to get it to work. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

This is my jQuery so far ...

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $('.tab-type-custom').each( function(e) {
        if( !$.trim( $(this).find('row').html() ).length ) {
            var ID = $(this).attr('id');
            $( '#'+ ID + '_toggle').hide()
        }
    });
});
```

These are my tabs

```
<div class="profile-menu">
   <ul id="descriptionTab" class="cts-carousel" style="position: relative;">
      <li> <a id="listing_tab_profile_toggle" data-section-id="profile" class="listing-tab-toggle toggle-tab-type-main" data-options="{}"> Profile </a> </li>
      <li class="active"> <a id="listing_tab_brands_toggle" data-section-id="brands" class="listing-tab-toggle toggle-tab-type-custom" data-options="{}"> Brands </a> </li>
      <li> <a id="listing_tab_dry-goods_toggle" data-section-id="dry-goods" class="listing-tab-toggle toggle-tab-type-custom" data-options="{}"> Dry Goods </a> </li>
      <li> <a id="listing_tab_reviews_toggle" data-section-id="reviews" class="listing-tab-toggle toggle-tab-type-comments" data-options="{}"> Reviews </a> </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And this is the content of the tabs (well two of them for simplicity). One with content, other no content/text, just HTML.

```
<!-- This is my tab content -->
<div class="tab-content listing-tabs">

    <!-- .tab-type-custom / has content / (also is active tab) -->
    <section class="profile-body listing-tab tab-type-custom tab-layout-content-sidebar pre-init tab-active" id="listing_tab_brands">
    <div class="container tab-template-content-sidebar">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="row cts-column-wrapper cts-left-column">
                <div class="col-md-12 block-type-terms" id="block_x1G2pTC">
                    <div class="element">
                        <div class="pf-head">
                            <div class="title-style-1">
                            <h5>  Brands  </h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pf-body">
                            <div class="listing-details item-count-8">
                                <p>

                                     Some content

                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 block-type-text" id="block_Lomkw5V">
                    <div class="element content-block plain-text-content">
                        <div class="pf-head">
                            <div class="title-style-1">
                                <h5>  More content  </h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pf-body">
                            <p>

                                Some content

                            </p>
                            <p>

                                Some content

                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>

    <!-- .tab-type-custom / has NO content / Trying to hide - as no content, just HTML -->

    <section class="profile-body listing-tab tab-hidden tab-type-custom tab-layout-content-sidebar pre-init" id="listing_tab_dry-goods">
    <div class="container tab-template-content-sidebar">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="row cts-column-wrapper cts-left-column"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="row cts-column-wrapper cts-right-column"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>

</div>
```

Comment: First you have a problem here in your html `data-id="780" "=""`. Second I think `.find('row')` should be `.find('.row')`

Comment: Please explain on what condition do you base "have no content" on.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen the tabs are populated from ACF (Advanced Custom fields) in WordPress.

Comment: but what would the html look like when it's empty ? if you mean if there is no content in `pf-body` then you have another problem

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen the second Section (marked as 'has NO content' is how its rendered. By no content I mean no text / content from the custom fields, but HTML div's are rendered.

Comment: I will add, if I add the jQuery to the <head> of the page all tabs are present. If I add the jQuery inline above the tabs HTML in a <script>, all the .tab-type-custom dont display, wether with content or not.

Comment: Rob I would advice you to fix those problems I explained at the start. But If the jquery select the id `listing_tab_aquariums` to remove then there is no element with `listing_tab_aquariums_toggle`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you for your advice, just looking into your first comment. Apologise I was cleaning up the rendered HTML for posting, its my mistake the aquariums class, have updated original posted code.

Comment: Cleaned up pasted HTML, my error regarding data-id, that should not be there and is not rendered. Have updated HTML. Tried .row, no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `!$.trim($(this).find('.row.cts-left-column').html()).length` since there is way to many `.row` to make it a good selector.

**Demo**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.tab-type-custom').each(function(e) {
    if (!$.trim($(this).find('.row.cts-left-column').html()).length) {
      var ID = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#' + ID + '_toggle').hide()
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="profile-menu">
  <ul id="descriptionTab" class="cts-carousel" style="position: relative;">
    <li> <a id="listing_tab_profile_toggle" data-section-id="profile" class="listing-tab-toggle toggle-tab-type-main" data-options="{}"> Profile </a> </li>
    <li class="active"> <a id="listing_tab_brands_toggle" data-section-id="brands" class="listing-tab-toggle toggle-tab-type-custom" data-options="{}"> Brands </a> </li>
    <li> <a id="listing_tab_dry-goods_toggle" data-section-id="dry-goods" class="listing-tab-toggle toggle-tab-type-custom" data-options="{}"> Dry Goods </a> </li>
    <li> <a id="listing_tab_reviews_toggle" data-section-id="reviews" class="listing-tab-toggle toggle-tab-type-comments" data-options="{}"> Reviews </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- This is my tab content -->
<div class="tab-content listing-tabs">

  <!-- .tab-type-custom / has content / (also is active tab) -->
  <section class="profile-body listing-tab tab-type-custom tab-layout-content-sidebar pre-init tab-active" id="listing_tab_brands">
    <div class="container tab-template-content-sidebar">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="row cts-column-wrapper cts-left-column">
            <div class="col-md-12 block-type-terms" id="block_x1G2pTC">
              <div class="element">
                <div class="pf-head">
                  <div class="title-style-1">
                    <h5> Brands </h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pf-body">
                  <div class="listing-details item-count-8">
                    <p>

                      Some content

                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 block-type-text" id="block_Lomkw5V">
              <div class="element content-block plain-text-content">
                <div class="pf-head">
                  <div class="title-style-1">
                    <h5> More content </h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pf-body">
                  <p>

                    Some content

                  </p>
                  <p>

                    Some content

                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- .tab-type-custom / has NO content / Trying to hide - as no content, just HTML -->

  <section class="profile-body listing-tab tab-hidden tab-type-custom tab-layout-content-sidebar pre-init" id="listing_tab_dry-goods">
    <div class="container tab-template-content-sidebar">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="row cts-column-wrapper cts-left-column"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="row cts-column-wrapper cts-right-column"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```